# How to ignore field depending on method?

Tags: java, json, spring, annotations, jackson

How to ignore filed field depending on method?

I have a question about Spring Jackson annotations.

I have a model class. Code:

```
public class Tenant{
@JsonIgnore
private String id;

@JsonProperty("id")
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringValueDeserializer.class)
private String idSIMC;

@JsonProperty("name")
private String displayName;

@JsonProperty("description")
private String description;

@JsonProperty("default")
private boolean def;

@JsonProperty("geoLoc")
@JsonDeserialize(using = GeoLocationIdNameDeserializer.class)
private GeoLocation geoLoc;

@JsonProperty("asnId")
private String asnId;

@JsonProperty("devices")
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringArrayIdDeserializer.class)
private List<String> tempDevice = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());


@JsonIgnore 
@JsonProperty("devices") // <-- I need to add this
private List<Device> devices = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

//getters and setters...
}
```

Now my question. I have method#1 that instance above class and write in tempDevice IDs of devices. method#2 get all devices from servers and filter them by tempDevice (I need to do it) can I annotate ( or something else ) my fields to be ignored as Json Objects depending on method is called?

method#1

```
public List<Tenant> getTenantsFromServer() {
    SSLVerification.disableSslVerification();
    ArrayList<Tenant> tenants = new ArrayList<>(0);

    String[] ids = getTenantIds();


    for(int i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
        ResponseEntity<ReturnUnique<Tenant>> result = getRestTemplate().exchange(getUrl() + SIEMCommands.ZONE_GET_ZONE + "?id=" + ids[i],
                HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(getHeader()), new ParameterizedTypeReference<ReturnUnique<Tenant>>(){});
        Tenant newTenant = result.getBody().getValue();
        newTenant.setParentNode(this);

        newTenant.generateId();
        tenants.add(newTenant);
    }
    return tenants;
}
```

In this method i have a key "devices" in that is stored id. In method#2 another json that also have "devices" key but with another dates.(name,ip, etc.) And when I execute this method I should to store all in **devices** list.

JSON used in first *method#1*

```
{"return": {
"asnId": 0,
"default": false,
"description": "",
"devices": [
    {"id": 144121785900597248},
    {"id": 144121785917374464},
    {"id": 144121785934151680}
],
"geoLoc": {
    "id": {"value": 0},
    "name": ""
},
"id": {"value": 1},
"name": "HA_Zone"
}}
```

devices values are written in tempDevice;

method#2 use this JSON

```
"devices": [{
                "CRuleRight": true,
                "FTestRight": true,
                "adRight": true,
                "addDeleteRight": false,
                "children": [],
                "clientCount": 0,
                "clientStatus": "0",
                "clientVipsInSync": false,
                "deviceActionRight": true,
                "deviceDisabled": false,
                "elmFile": false,
                "elmHasSAN": false,
                "eventRight": true,
                "hostname": "",
                "ipAddress": "172.28.60.17",
                "ipsID": "144121785950928896",
                "ipsRight": true,
                "name": "ASA Admin CTX Site 2",
                "parent": false,
                "polRight": true,
                "protocol": "gsyslog",
                "reportRight": true,
                "status": "6",
                "statusAck": "0",
                "tpcCollector": "syslog",
                "tpcType": "278",
                "type": "VIPS",
                "viewRight": true,
                "vipsEnabled": true,
                "vipsID": "49",
                "vipsInSync": false
            },
            {
                "CRuleRight": true,
                "FTestRight": true,
                "adRight": true,
                "addDeleteRight": false,
                "children": [],
                "clientCount": 0,
                "clientStatus": "0",
                "clientVipsInSync": false,
                "deviceActionRight": true,
                "deviceDisabled": false,
                "elmFile": false,
                "elmHasSAN": false,
                "eventRight": true,
                "hostname": "",
                "ipAddress": "172.28.13.10",
                "ipsID": "144121785179176960",
                "ipsRight": true,
                "name": "ASA-VPN-DC1",
                "parent": false,
                "polRight": true,
                "protocol": "gsyslog",
                "reportRight": true,
                "status": "0",
                "statusAck": "0",
                "tpcCollector": "syslog",
                "tpcType": "278",
                "type": "VIPS",
                "viewRight": true,
                "vipsEnabled": true,
                "vipsID": "3",
                "vipsInSync": false
            }
        }]
```

this dates i have to write in **devices**

Comment: I'm not sure I actually understand your question (some example might be helpful) but you could try and remove the annotations and add them via mixins in your methods, i.e. register them on the object mapper (via `addMixInAnnotations()` on `SerializationConfig` and/or `DeserializationConfig`).

Comment: @Thomas I update my question

Comment: I still don't get it from your description (with example I meant some relevant data and the json you want to generate from it) and the code you added suggests you're using a webservice, is that correct? So are you calling Jackson manually or do you just pass the resulting list to the webservice framework? If you do the latter I'm not sure how to add mixins there so either look that up in the documentation or try to call Jackson manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to deserialize 2 different json datatype having same property name into a object in different situation. If that is the case, the suggestion of using [JacksonMixInAnnotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) from @Thomas should work. JacksonMixInAnnotations can provide a kind of way to add annotation from another class (called mix-in class) to the target class during run time.

In your case, you can left `tempDevice` and `devices` without Jackson annotation like follows:

```
public class Tenant {

    private List<String> tempDevice;

    private List<Device> devices;

}
```

and declare 2 mix-in classes:

```
abstract class TempDeviceMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("devices")
    private List<String> tempDevice;
}

abstract class DeviceMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("devices")
    private List<Device> devices;
}
```

When you need to deserialize a json string with a string property of `devices`, you can add mix-in class annotation likes:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Tenant.class, TempDeviceMixIn.class);
Tenant tenant = mapper.readValue(json, Tenant.class);
```

Deserialize a json string with a object property of `devices` is similar.

As you are using `RestTemplate`, you will need a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` with your `ObjectMapper`.